# For /F loop how to cut quotes from a result using awk or tr

Tags: batch-file

I'm having a bit of trouble with a batch script which needs to parse a value out of an config file into a variable. the issue is the wanting to cut " from a value

from 
    "enabled"
to 
     enabled

```
    for /f "tokens=*" %%d in ('C:\example.exe -devgs !ID1!;!ID2! ^| grep.exe accountState ^| awk.exe -F "(: )" "{print $2}"') do set State=%%d
echo !State!
"enabled"
```

if i try to Awk or TR and remove the quotes around the results, it fails

```
    for /f "tokens=*" %%d in ('C:\example.exe -devgs !ID1!;!ID2! ^| grep.exe accountState ^| awk.exe -F "(: )" "{print $2}" ^| tr.exe -d """') do set State=%%d
echo !State!
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
```

```
    for /f "tokens=*" %%d in ('C:\example.exe -devgs !ID1!;!ID2! ^| grep.exe accountState ^| awk.exe -F "(: )" "{print $2}" ^| tr.exe -d ^"') do set State=%%d
echo !State!
"enabled"
```

Comment: What happens if you change the end of your command line to `Do Set "State=%%~d"`?

Comment: `"""` are unbalanced quotes, so the remaining command line appears quoted to `cmd.exe`; so (in case `%%~d` does not help), try replacing them with `^"""` (first quote escaped)...

Comment: From the `FOR` help file: `%~I         - expands %I removing any surrounding quotes (")`

Comment: Thanks this worked

```
tr.exe -d ^"') Do Set "accountState=%%~d"

Comment: This also worked ```

tr.exe -d ^"""') do set accountState=%%d